# When converting Panda Dataframe to Excel, long strings in cells are getting truncated

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have strings that exceed 255 characters, and they are getting cut off when I convert from panda to excel using:

```
sources.to_excel("sources.xlsx")
```

How do I prevent this truncation?

Comment: Split them before converting to excel.

Comment: Is the text truncated or wrapped? [Excel cells can contain 32K characters but a column's width can be only 255 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Seeing the same problem in 2022 still :(

Answer (score 0):

The strings will be stored in a single column.
Just expand the width of the column in excel to contain those strings in a single cell.

Comment: I know that I can view the whole cell by expanding the width. However, when I call sources = pd.read_excel("sources.xlsx") after having saved the dataframe, and refer to a specific value of a cell. It is truncated.